# How do I get a sound to fire on local machine when I run a bash script on a remote computer via SSH?

Tags: linux, bash, memory-management, ssh

I have a script that makes a beep when too much memory is used. I would like to deploy this script to a remote computer and run it through SSH. Unfortunately, it makes the remote computer beep and not mine. Is there any way around this?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Peter Black
# alarm.sh
max_percent=94
sleeper=1
frequency=1000
duration=300

# To enable the script:
# chmod u+x alert.sh

# get the total available memory:
function total_memory {
    echo "Total memory available: "
    TOTAL_MEM=$(grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}')
    #Another way of doing that:
    #total_mem=$(awk '/MemTotal/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo)
    echo "---------- $TOTAL_MEM ---------------"
}


# alarm function params: frequency, duration
# Example:
# _alarm 400 200
_alarm() {
  ( \speaker-test --frequency $1 --test sine )&
  pid=$!
  \sleep 0.${2}s
  \kill -9 $pid
}

function total_available_memory {
    total_available_mem=$(</proc/meminfo grep MemTotal | grep -Eo '[0-9]+')
    total_free_mem=$(</proc/meminfo grep MemFree | grep -Eo '[0-9]+')
    total_used_mem=$((total_available_mem - total_free_mem))
    #percent_used=$((total_available_mem / total_free_mem))
    # print the free memory
    # customize the unit based on the format of your /proc/meminfo
    percent_used=$(printf '%i %i' $total_used_mem $total_available_mem | awk '{ pc=100*$1/$2; i=int(pc); print (pc-i<0.5)?i:i+1 }')

    if [ $percent_used -gt $max_percent ]; then
        echo "TOO MUCH MEMORY IS BEIGN USED!!!!!!!! KILL IT!"
        _alarm $frequency $duration
    fi

    echo "Available: $total_available_mem kb  -  Used: $total_used_mem kb  -  Free: $total_free_mem kb  -  Percent Used: $percent_used %"

}

# RUN THE FUNCTIONS IN AN INFINITE LOOP:
# total_memory

echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
while :
do
    total_available_memory
    sleep $sleeper
done
```

Comment: Then you'll have to write a server for your machine and make the remote host send some data to yours so the server can process it and do a beep.

Comment: You can react to a specific output message from the script and trigger the sound on the local machine or do what ForceBru suggested.

Comment: Can I write a script that runs on the local machine to SSH in to the remote one and query the memory?

Comment: If you create an ssh certificate and install it on the remote machine to give your process privileged access you could simply `total_available_mem=$(ssh <user>@<host> </proc/meminfo grep MemTotal | grep -Eo '[0-9]+')` to get the values from the remote machine and run the script locally.  If you don't set up the ssh certificates, you have to enter the password manually.  :(

Comment: A link that will [help you set up ssh certs](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) .

Comment: No matter which authentication method is in use, one would want to use a ControlMaster configuration to avoid the performance overhead of re-authenticating for every poll if implementing the suggestion from @pedwards.

Comment: I was wondering about overhead. Thanks! I will look into it. Since this monitors memory, I will build in a way to check latency and load as well. Its really just running when we are aware that there may be a problem. So, it should not be a big deal. I ended up using pedwards advice and it boils down to 2 ssh calls per loop. This is a good solution for now..

Comment: EEK! Does not seem to be working... total_available_mem=$(ssh <user>@<host> </proc/meminfo grep MemTotal | grep -Eo '[0-9]+') seems to make a connection but it is returning the MemTotal from my local machine...? Why would it make the connection only to run the command on local?

Answer (score 1):

Being bash, simply print the "bell" character a few times instead of using your speaker-test program...  `echo -e "\007\007\007"` It makes sounds locally even in the script you are executing on the remote machine.  Frequency and volume are a different issue...

Edit:   better yet, sleep after each bell so you can hear it!  :)

```
for i in {0..10}
do
    echo -en "\007"
    sleep 0.5
done
```

Comment: What is your environment?

Comment: This command will make sound on the remote client, and not on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a very simple way:

```
ls -l >/dev/dsp
```

:-)

It will channel a directory text into the sound output as if it would be a wav file. It doesn't sound very well :-) but for alarming it is wonderful. It requires to have the kernel module producing the `/dev/dsp` device.

This works only on older Linuxes, because `/dev/dsp` exists only on that.

---

Alternatively, you can also beep on a character terminal of the console, but you need to redirect the beep output into that:

```
echo -en "\007" >/dev/tty1
```

will do what you want. But it requires a turned on speaker and active console desktop (it X server runs, maybe it won't work).

Comment: Doesn't work on MacOS.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha Can any other console thing beep at you? Note, showing a `\007` as beep is only a... custom, actually nothing constraints MacOS to follow this custom.

Comment: I meant `ls -l >/dev/dsp`. No such file on MacOS.  `echo -en "\007"` without redirection actually works.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha That is a Linux-specific thing. /dev/dsp is a device of the first sound card in older linuxes, what you write there. I edit the post.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha Look this: https://github.com/mame/osxdsp That seems a /dev/dsp emulator for OSX. I have just found it by google, I have no idea if it works or not.